# How to initialize the SDK with this code snippet for iOS app using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sdk, firebase-realtime-database

I need your help. I am developing a App using Swift language and Firebase as a database. I am trying to initialize SDK with a code. I am confused, in which file I have to add this code snippet? HTML or a new swift file or?

I am stuck in this step https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Hope you guys will help me. Thank you in advance.

Below is the code snippet example:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be following the wrong directions. This is for adding the Firebase Admin SDK to a server -- not setting up access to the database from an iOS client.

I'd recommend following the directions here instead: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: Hi Todd,  

I am following this instructions to writing programs that manage susers in Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Any more help would be appreciated!!